# Menu for /user page

Tags: routes

How to edit menu for `/user` page? I can't find this menu in the dashboard.

I have:

```
View
Edit
Orders
Shortcuts
Track page visits
Devel
```

Comment: these are related menu tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The menu you're referring is named "menu local task". Usually you can edit this menu in different ways like:

- implementing hook_menu().
- Creating a view with a "menu tab" and a matching path.

The first way needs a bit of programming. You've to create a custom Drupal module which implements hook_menu() and add the entry.

The second option is more easy:

1. Create a view with a "page" display
2. Set /user/custom-subpath as "path"
3. Select "Default menu tab" or "menu tab"

**EDIT**: if you need to remove an item you can implement hook_menu_alter() and unset the unwanted items in this way:

```
function yourmodulename_menu_alter(&$items){
  unset($items['path/to/remove']);
}
```

Good work,
bye.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching path"? How to edit this menu in the dashboard?

Comment: It seem that hook_menu can only add items, but I need to remove "Create new account" item from the menu

Comment: If you need to remove an item you can do in three ways: 1) hide from CSS (quite ugly); 2) implement hook_menu_alter() and unset the unwanted items (I've edited the answer with an example)